# TSLint allow-fast-null-checks not working for me

Tags: typescript, webstorm, tslint

My tslint.json contains

```
"no-unused-expression": [true, "allow-fast-null-checks"],
```

The exact code I have is:

```
let x: number;
let test = !!(Math.random() % 2);
test && (x = 1);
// ^-- Error (no-unused-expression)
console.log(x);
```

I thought the purpose of `alow-fast-null-checks` was to allow the above, am I mistaken?

**EDIT:** It now works as expected, sadly I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: Are you seeing this error at the command line or in your text editor? If it is in the text editor, what editor are you using?

Comment: in my text editor, WebStorm, it goes away if i set `no-unused-expressions` to false.

Comment: Does the same problem occur when you run tslint from the command line?

Comment: Nope, if i run `tsc` on it, it doesn't complain. It just shows the squiggly red mark in my editor and says the error i mentioned when i mouseover. P.S. thanks for letting me know this was webstorm related, i didnt know.

Comment: Our team is using WebStorm and VSCode for TypeScript development. We've found it non-trivial to make WebStorm follow the rules in our tslint and our tsconfig.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin tbh ive just disabled `no-unused-expression` and moved on, if you know how to make it work (not say its an error) let me know though, id prefer to leave it enabled. From what I read in the documentation `allow-fast-null-check` was added for this specific reason. The overall experience of using ts with webstorm has been amazing :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151755/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-leathan).